# Extracting Sqlite Database file from Android Device

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Nexus device that I try to extract sqlite database from my app. I use adb shell to connect to the device. I locate the database file, but I can't copy it to my computer. I have Windows 10. In shell, it doesn't seem to recognize my local paths. Does anyone know a workaround? How can I specify my local computer's file system as the destination for the cp command in adb shell?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you can copy your database from the application data path (example: /data/com.example.mine.move/databases/A.db) using adb shell.. the path is protected.